# node self-references in enqueing loop

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, local-variables, huffman-code

I am implementing a Huffman encoder. Huffman trees are built bottom-up using a priority queue. I have a simple node class with pointers to two other nodes.
The loop that builds the tree is:

```
while(q.size() > 1)
{
    huffnode n1 = q.top();
    q.pop();
    huffnode n2 = q.top();
    q.pop();

    q.push(huffnode((char)0, n1.freq+n2.freq, &n1, &n2));
}
```

The remaining node when the loop terminates is the tree root.

This code looks innocent enough, but on my test input it gives a tree where the root's right child points to itself and to the root's left child instead of to the two nodes that were just popped from the queue. I have confirmed that the queue is sorted correctly.

What I think is happening is that n1 and n2 are local variables that always have the same address, as seen in the debugger. When a new node is pushed, it points to those addresses. When that node gets popped later, its copy gets put into one of those addresses, one of which it is already pointing to, so it ends up pointing to itself.

How should I fix this? I can't make n1 and n2 pointers, because then they would have to be `const` since top() returns a const reference, and assigning the result of top() to a const reference or const pointer makes the queue immutable.

Comment: The addresses `&n1, &n2` are invalidated after the `while` loop is left. You are dealing with dangling pointers (whatever you do).

Comment: if that is the case, then why can I follow the root's pointers after the loop terminates?

Answer (score 2):

When you have the curly braces `{}` you are in a new scope. and variables declared in that scope are local to that scope and only valid inside that scope. When the scope ends, which for you your loop is every time the loop iterates, the scope disappears and the variables in that scope are destructed and exists no more.

Saving a pointer to a variable that goes out of scope will lead to *undefined behavior* when you try to dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have garbage collection, and does not allocate objects on the heap unless you tell it to -- you need to manage your memory yourself.

If you want to build a dynamically allocated tree, you need to allocate your nodes on the heap explicitly, by using `new` or some higher-level library facility.  You will also need to make sure they are destroyed when you know that there are no more references to them.

As others have mentioned, your `huffnode` variables `n1` and `n2` are local variables, and are destroyed when they go out of scope (which is, every pass of your `while` loop).

Comment: I know the local variables are destroyed when they go out of scope but my debugger shows they always have the same addresses in each iteration. Perhaps the compiler does this as a loop optimization so the program does not have to make expensive memory requests each iteration. The point is, just because n1 and n2 are destroyed at the end of each iteration doesn't mean they won't occupy the same memory at the beginning of the next iteration.

Comment: But if you want to build a tree out of them, you can't just reuse the same memory  --  you need to allocate a separate object for each node!  In C++, if you declare a local object variable, the *actual object* is stored on the stack, and is *actually destroyed* when it goes out of scope.  This is unlike Java, which allocates all objects on its heap, only stores references in its local variables, and will keep the allocated objects around until they are garbage-collected.

Comment: So, you need to allocate each separate node (using `new`).  Your local variables should be *pointers* (of some sort) to the resulting heap-allocated objects.

Answer (score 0):

comingstorm is right. I need to use `new`.

The fixed code is

```
while(q.size() > 1)
{
    huffnode* n1 = new huffnode(q.top().data, q.top().freq, q.top().left, q.top().right);
    q.pop();
    huffnode* n2 = new huffnode(q.top().data, q.top().freq, q.top().left, q.top().right);
    q.pop();

    q.push(huffnode((char)0, n1->freq + n2->freq, n1, n2));
}
```